# How do I expose an enum to users of my library in a public header file but also use it internally?

Tags: c++, header-files

If I am creating a library that exposes one public header file, which may take or return a publicly exposed `enum`, how would I use that `enum` internally without also creating a circular dependency in header files?

For example :

**Public.h**

```
#include "Internal.h"


namespace PublicFunctions {
    enum Access{
        READ,
        WRITE,
    }

    FileObject CreateFileObject(Access a) {
        return InternalFunctions::GetFileObject(a);
    }
}
```

**Internal.h**

```
#include "Public.h"


namespace InternalFunctions {

    FileObject GetFileObject(PublicFunctions::Access a);
}
```

**Internal.cpp**

```
FileObject InternalFunctions::GetFileObject(PublicFunctions::Access a) {
    if (a == PublicFunctions::Read) {
          return openreadonly();
    }
    else {
              return openwrite();
    }
}
```

I know about the `#praga` once preprocessor directive, but is there any way to forward declare an `enum` in these internal files ?

Or is `#pragma` once the best method to resolve these dependencies ?

Comment: public including internal would expose the internal details. You may want to move the implementation of `CreateFileObject` to a cpp file where these details can remain hidden.

Comment: Using include guards seems the most straightforward way to take care of this unless I'm missing something. Is there any situation where you wouldn't put include guards on your header files?

Comment: Why is `Public.h` including `Internal.h`? If it's public, it should not have any access to anything internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An include guard cannot help you because if public.h is included first, the logical case for the library's clients, you will wind up with

```cpp
// public.h already included so #include "Public.h" is ignored 
namespace InternalFunctions {

    FileObject GetFileObject(PublicFunctions::Access a);
    // PublicFunctions::Access not defined yet.
}

namespace PublicFunctions {
    enum Access{
        READ,
        WRITE,
    }

    FileObject CreateFileObject(Access a) {
        return InternalFunctions::GetFileObject(a);
    }
}
```

Worse anyone who includes public.h gets a peek into internals.h, which defeats the point of separating the two.

But if you remove `CreateFileObject`'s implementation from public.h you can

```cpp
namespace PublicFunctions {
    enum Access{
        READ,
        WRITE,
    }

    FileObject CreateFileObject(Access a);
}
```

and leave internal.h alone. It will be used exclusively by the compiled library and not be shipped with the public interface.

```cpp
#include "Public.h"

namespace InternalFunctions {

    FileObject GetFileObject(PublicFunctions::Access a);
}
```

and then Internal.cpp

```cpp
#include "internal.h"
FileObject InternalFunctions::GetFileObject(PublicFunctions::Access a) {
    if (a == PublicFunctions::Read) {
          return openreadonly();
    }
    else {
              return openwrite();
    }
}
```

and finally public.cpp

```cpp
#include "internal.h"
FileObject PublicFunctions::CreateFileObject(Access a) {
        return InternalFunctions::GetFileObject(a);
    }
```

Whether it is worth separating public.cpp and internal.cpp is up to the programmer and their coding standard.